# Отладка C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder, ide

Как в С++ Builder сделать дебаг? А то у меня ошибка в программе. Хочу найти, а билдер мне показывает окно с ассемблером. Ну, я не настолько крут, чтобы разгребать прогу > 1мб...

Мне просто надо построчно пройти функцию. В ней где-то ошибка, которая возникает в процессе работы программы.

Нужен такой отладчик, как в Visual C++.

Comment: А Вы отлаживаете какую программу? Свою с исходными кодами в C++ Builder или стороннюю?

Comment: Свою программу.

Answer (score 2):

Ставим брекпоинт, запускаем прогу через IDE ... а там уже пошагово трейсите ..
Я вообще не понимаю какие могут возникнуть проблемы.

Comment: Все, разобрался, спасибо!